# Database syncronization of Remote Database to Local Database and vice versa using Python

Tags: python, synchronization, remote-access

I'd like to ask regarding syncronizing records between remote database and local database using Python program. I am just a newbie on Python Language and would like to seek assistance on these one.

If what's the process, technology and a sample for these kind of problem. I have a Website where in it contains selling products and services. Visitors may sign up in order for them to order products or services.

I'd like to make a Python program which fetches information/records unto my python desktop application according to the Email and Password of the client which will be set initially on the once the program runs.

The concept is like Dropbox though the difference is that on my end I'd like to syncronize records, when the client orders on his/her local machine even offline the information will be saved locally and will be uploaded on the remote server ones he/she connects to the internet.

Thanks in advance for the help.